# Is it possible to add a year to column in REST query?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

Is it possible to add a year to column in REST query

```
 /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=Modified&$filter=Modified ge '" + Today.toISOString() + "' and Modified le '" + SomeDate.toISOString() + "'
```

Is it possible to add 1 year to **Modified** Column in above query and filter?

Basically, I want to filter the result based on modified date plus 1 year.

Answer (score 3):

Could you not just subtract one year from the dates you are using to filter?

```
var startDate = (today - 1 year).toISOString();
var endDate = (someDate - 1 year).toISOString();

/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=Modified&$filter=Modified ge '" + startDate + "' and Modified le '" + endDate + "'
```

---

Addressing your comment:

I don't think you can specify a filter in that way because to know what `Modified + 1 yr` is, you would have to first retrieve the value of `Modified` in a separate REST call.

My point is that you can manipulate the dates you use to filter so that they have the same relationship to `Modified` as what you want when you are thinking about `Modified + 1 yr`.

Let's look at this logically - you say your start date for filtering is `today` and your end date for filtering is `today + 30 days`, but what you are trying to compare against is `Modified + 1 yr`.

Today is `26-09-2017`, today + 30 days is `26-10-2017`.  A date that falls within that range is `01-10-2017`.  In order for `Modified + 1 yr` to be `01-10-2017`, the actual `Modified` date would have to be `01-10-2016`.

Can we construct a query that will capture a document with a `Modified` date of `01-10-2016`?  Yes we can:

Today (`26-09-2017`) minus one year = `26-09-2016`.

Today + 30 days (`26-10-2017`) minus one year = `26-10-2016`.

`26-09-2016` <= `01-10-2016` <= `26-10-2016` ?  Yes, that satisfies the query, and would find an item who's `Modified + 1 yr` falls between `today` and `today + 30 days`.

Now, I may not be understanding exactly what you are trying to filter for, but I think my point still stands - you can manipulate your filter start and end dates so that they have the same relationship with `Modified` that you are looking for when you are thinking about wanting to filter for `Modified + 1yr`.

Alternatively, another thing you could try would be to add a calculated column that adds a year to the `Modified` date, and filter on that column instead.

Comment: No. Actually i want to filter for dates in future. Modified+1 will give me review date column and start/end will be today and today+30days

Comment: @SharePointGoa updated my answer.

Comment: I completely understand your logic and actually i did the same thing before putting this question here. Also, i would be going for the same thing if i can not find something better than this.